# Get Size of Collections in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I was excited to see an idea I was about to post, already delivered (rare happenstance with me and Salesforce), but apparently the release notes just link to the ideas page that says it was delivered Summer 18' but no details/instructions to implement it.

[Idea: Get Size of Collections in Flow](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dgp6AAC)

Anyone know how to get size of Collection within a Flow?

Comment: You can follow this blog: https://sfdcian.com/get-size-of-collections-in-flow-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's cleverly hidden in the section titled "Update Active Stages and Collections with New Assignment Operators" in the release notes. Basically, you can use an assignment formula to determine the size of your collection:

```
{!myCollectionSize} equals count {!myCollection}
```

And from there, you can then use that value in conditional controls, etc.

Comment: In 2023, is there a way to use a Formula resource in a Flow to retrieve the `count` of a collection?

Comment: @kennyc I don't think so. I'm pretty sure I'd have known about it if it was.

Comment: An step by step explanation of this solution: https://sfdcian.com/get-size-of-collections-in-flow-in-salesforce/