# Is there a way to interact with other records in the same transaction using record triggered flow?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, transaction

I need to access to all the records that are in the same transaction using a record triggered flow as you can do with triggers using Trigger.New() that returns you all the record in the same transaction and loop over them. Is there a way to achieve that behaviour using record triggered flows?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you "need" to access the other records in the transaction? What are you trying to do? This may be an [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @sfdcfox because I need to update a counter on a parent record. Let me make an example: if I was using a trigger and 200 child records were updated I would have them in the trigger.New() list so I can do something like ParentRecord.Counter += Trigger.New().size(). On the other hand the record triggered flow seems to always act a single unit so it seems you don't have the possibility to know about other interviews, then if I try to update the counter (let's say that is setted to 0 at the start point) the counter will be added for just 1 unit.

Comment: why not just use DLRS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't share state between flows in the same transaction directly. From your given example in the comments, there are at least two possible solutions to the "let's build our own rollup feature" scenario.

The first solution is to use a post-save Record-Triggered Flow on the child to update the parent, and then use a pre-save Record-Triggered Flow on the Parent to count the children (see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234240/get-size-of-collections-in-flow) on how to get collection size in Flows). This may have performance problems scaling up, but it could work for most typical use cases (presuming you're avoiding [Parent-Child Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm)). The last I recall, though, you still can't update the parent more than 12 times in a single DML statement, so bulkification would likely be limited to just 12 records in a single DML statement.

The second solution is to write an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm); this method is bulkified, so all flows that stop at this element at the same time will be visible to Apex. You can then build out a collection for each interview to have essentially a shared state. Of course, now we're talking about writing some code, but the overall solution would use far less code than a trigger. Because of the aforementioned limit of 12 simultaneous updates to a single parent, I would recommend you set a flag in the return value, such that only one child per parent is allowed to update the parent, and the others would skip to the next step/end.